# Merging Rows containing ColumnA predicated by next result(s) of ColumnA

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want the result to display the amount of instances a particular catering has been booked for.

If the next row has the same catering they should be summed together.

If the next row does not have the same catering the previous row should be output.

### Sample Data

[image: Dataset 1]

[image: Dataset 2]

### Expected Output

[image: Expected output 1]

[image: Expected Output 2]

I have currently implemented a *Cursor based* solution which works fine for my dataset but the code is cumbersome.

Can someone suggest a *set based* solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for `GROUP BY`?

```
select text, count(*)
from t
group by text;
```

EDIT:

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  A simple method uses the difference of row numbers:

```
select text, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by rn) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by text order by rn) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
group by text, (seqnum - seqnum_t);
```

The difference of row numbers defines the grouping you want.  This is a little cumbersome to explain, but if you run the subquery, you will probably see that this works.

Comment: A simple Group by for the first sample data would result in 2x Frühstuck, 1x Halbpension. It would only work for the second data set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I was looking for